# Ink color mixing with hex codes?

Tags: colors, rgb

How can we mix colors with hex codes? For example yellow+blue=green ffff00+0000ff=00ff00. Whats algorithm for this?

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?

In most languages, we can mask out the R, G, B components and do addition and clipping (fitting to range [0, 255]) separately.
There may be libraries on the particular language that can do the addition for you.